# not submitting leaderboard score & not display leaderboard

Tags: android, google-api-client, leaderboard

submit leaderboard score

I was tried this below code but a score was not submitting.

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(this.mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_star_connect), (long) 722);
```

show leaderboard

I was tried this below code but leaderboard was not displaying.

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(this.mGoogleApiClient,getString(R.string.leaderboard_star_connect)), GG_RC_UNUSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

set upload SHA1 KEY in our Google API console.your problem will be solved.

- you will test Application  After making sign Apk & After uploaded  Sign Apk to Developer Console.